# when should I favor local 1byte encoding like Windows over UTF-8?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

Local encodings like Windows-1251 take up 1 byte per character, while UTF-8 requires 2 bytes per character for Russian charset (beyond 127th number), which means the fileize doubles. However, by using UTF-8 I save myself troubles in the future which can manifest itself by displaying characters incorrectly. So my question is when should I favor local 1byte encoding like Windows over UTF-8?

Comment: My off-the-cuff answer would be "when it fits". If you *know* the environment is restricted to one that can display the format correctly *and* you know you won't (ever, really) need UTF-8, then use it.

Comment: UTF-8 requires only one byte for characters in the range 0..127 (i.e., ASCII).

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'm using Russian charset which is beyond 127 number. But thanks for you remark

Comment: You should probably mention that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use UTF-8.

There is no good reason to use win1251 or any other 1-byte encoding.